# Java permanently running Task to check time

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, quarkus, stopwatch

I have written a task that runs as Scheduled (every Second). I need this scheduled method to monitor the lifetime of a bearer token.

I'm new to Java and wondering if there isn't a better, more elegant solution. I didn't find anything suitable using the search. Maybe I also used the wrong terms.

I used: StopWatch (org.apache.commons commons-lang3 Version 3.13.0)
To build and test, I use Maven and Quarkus. (io.quarkus.scheduler.Scheduled)

My Scheduled Method:

```
@Scheduled(every = "1s")
    public void checkStopuhr() {
        if (stopwatch.isStarted() && (stopwatch.getTime() / 1000) >= maxLifetimeBearerToken) {
            try {
                //System.out.println("Stopuhr vor reset: " + stopwatch.getTime());
                refreshBearer(clientAppId);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.atError().log("Error Methode: ServiceTokenImpl.checkStopuhr(), Fehler beim Erstellen eines neuen Bearer-Tokens.");
            }
        } else if(stopwatch.isStarted() && (stopwatch.getTime()/1000) > (maxLifetimeBearerToken + 1)){
            logger.atWarn().log("Die Stopuhr funktioniert nicht richtig. Sie wurde ausgelöst bei {} Sekunden",stopwatch.getTime()/1000);

        } else {
            if(stopwatch.isStarted()){
                System.out.println("verstrichene Zeit = " +stopwatch.getTime()/1000);
            }
        }
    }
```

Maybe one of you has a good idea that is understandable for me as a beginner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you know the lifetime of the token, you can schedule a one time task to refresh it at the right time. I'll use java's scheduler to demonstrate the logic, it should be fairly easy to translate to the framework you are using.

```
//get the token
long maxLifetimeBearerToken = //get validity from token
ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
Runnable refreshTokenAction = () -> {
  //refresh the token
  //register next task
};
service.schedule(refreshTokenAction, maxLifetimeBearerToken, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);//or other timeunit, depending on what is maxLifetimeBearerToken
```

This uses [ScheduledExecutorService.submit()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#schedule(java.lang.Runnable,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) to register a task for single execution:

> Submits a one-shot task that becomes enabled after the given delay.

Comment: Good morning. Can you explain me what are the main differences and advantages between your code and mine?

I tried actually this: @Scheduled(every = maxLifetimeBearerToken+"s", skipExecutionIf = TestPredicate.class)

Comment: @MartinH The advantage of this approach is that you refresh the token with a single operation, while your current approach uses many operations. If the token is valid for  1 hour, you will do 3600 checks and all of them, except for the last one are simply not needed.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and when I think about my solution, you are absolutely right. I will change it. Thank you very much and have a good start into the weekend.